# std::get_time() in gcc 6.3 and clang 4.0 doesn't work for full month names

Tags: c++, date, gcc, clang

I want to parse a date string with `std::get_time()`, but it seems the code works on VC++ 2015, but does not work on gcc 6.3 and clang 4.0. Here is the MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::string line = "February 4 1993 15:21";

    std::tm date_1 = {};

    std::stringstream ss(line);

    ss >> std::get_time(&date_1, "%b %d %Y %H:%M");

    if(ss.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "parse failed\n";
    }

    std::cout << date_1.tm_year << "\n";
    std::cout << date_1.tm_mon << "\n";
    std::cout << date_1.tm_mday << "\n";
    std::cout << date_1.tm_hour << "\n";
    std::cout << date_1.tm_min << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the result for VC++ 2015:

```
93
1
4
15
21
```

Here are the results for gcc 6.3.2 and clang 4.0 (I've used compilers on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) and [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)) - both with and without c++14 flags:

```
parse failed
0
1
0
0
0
```

It does work when I use abbreviated month names, such as Feb, Aug etc.

I've tried setting different locales on `stringstream` (`en_US`, `en_GB` + UTF-8 versions) but they either made no difference or resulted in runtime errors. I've tried changing separators but no difference as well.

I've read on [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) that %b in `std::get_time()`:

> parses the month name, **either full** or abbreviated, e.g. Oct

Is this a bug/missing functionality in both gcc and clang or are compilers, contrary to what's written above, free to handle only abbreviated names depending on the implementation? What does the standard say about that? Is it a coincidence that the two compilers exhibit the same behaviour here?

Comment: Bug of libstdc++. [Works with clang -stdlib=libc++.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3108a8e1c8921d9a)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=78714

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a libstdc++ bug.  Not noted however is how to work around it.

Use `%B` instead of `%b`, and libstdc++ will do the parse.  For parsing, `%B` and `%b` should have identical behavior.  But for formatting, `%B` outputs the locale's full month name while `%b` formats the abbreviated month name.

Finally, you may be interested in [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date-time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) which allows you to parse directly into `<chrono>` time points and durations:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::istringstream in{"February 4 1993 15:21"};
    sys_time<minutes> tp;
    in >> parse("%B %d %Y %H:%M", tp);
    if (in.fail())
        return 1;
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1993-02-04 15:21
```

In the example above `sys_time<minutes>` is a type alias for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::minutes>`.